# Android Web view assets not working

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I view web pages with your view, but I get an error page not found How can I solve?

```
  wv.loadUrl("file:///src/main/assets/index.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

`src/main/assets/` is a path on your development machine. It is not a path on the device.

Comment: Not working.
  wv.loadUrl("src/main/assets/index.html");

Comment: @Selahattin: You will notice that my answer does not contain `wv.loadUrl("src/main/assets/index.html")`.

Comment: How do I turn now well understood hm @CommonsWare

Comment: How do I open page in the application?

Comment: okay  wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); working :)